Connect to Podman Oracle Free Image using Sql Developer
I installed Oracle Sql developer and podman in my ubuntu 24.04 client/host .
With podman i did
podman run -d --name oracle-db -p 1521:1521 container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest

then set a simple password with this other command:
podman exec oracle-db ./setPassword.sh Password1
podman port oracle-db
1521/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:1521

but when I connect to it I keep getting all sorts of errors see image.
So It is my understanding that now I should be able to connect to localhost:1521 as SYSDBA using FREE sid. Alas I keep getting the error ORA-01017. Does anyone knows how should I connect to it?
documentation is here https://www.oracle.com/eg/database/free/get-started/ and here https://container-registry.oracle.com/ → databases → free . I get the image up and running but can't connect to it using sql developer.

it is working if i select SYS with role SYSDBA and Service Name FREEPDB1

Connect to root database (FREE)
export TWO_TASK=localhost/FREE
sqlplus sys/Welcome_#1 as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Nov 26 15:33:38 2024
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 23ai Free Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Develop, Learn, and Run for Free
Version 23.5.0.24.07

sys@FREE> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 FREEPDB1                       READ WRITE NO

Connect to pluggable database FREEPDB1
export TWO_TASK=localhost/FREEPDB1
sqlplus sys/Welcome_#1 as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Nov 26 15:33:27 2024
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 23ai Free Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Develop, Learn, and Run for Free
Version 23.5.0.24.07

sys@FREEPDB1> 

For multitenant architecture, you no longer use SID. You can, but don't go there. SERVICE_NAME is the way to connect using sqlplus, sqlcl or SQL Developer.
Best of luck!

it is working if i select SYS with role SYSDBA and Service Name FREEPDB1
